# automatically generating a list of links

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, methods, hyperlink

Ok so I am trying to make a list of links in a page that is generated using a `foreach` and loop as long as there are objects in the list. Here is the code that I use to generate the links:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["mamlist"] != null)
            {
                mamlist = (List<mammifere>)Session["mamlist"];

                int i = 0;
                foreach (mammifere l in mamlist)
                {
                    mamol.InnerHtml += ("<li><a onClick='select("+i+");' >" + l.Nom + "</a></li>");
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason, the links are unclickable. I get this:

[image: screenshot of the links]

How can I make links that do not lead to another page but instead launch a method in the `C#` code of the page?

Comment: You have double quotes inside single quotes, inside double quotes...

Comment: If you look closely, you will see that it is 3 separate double quotes. The double quotes are to make the content text and the single quotes are used as the actual html markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [`LinkButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) controls that call subroutines/methods in your ASPX code:

Sample code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>LinkButton Example</title>
<script language="C#" runat="server">

      void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
      {
         Label1.Text="You clicked the link button";
      }

   </script>

</head>
<body>

   <form id="form1" runat="server">

      <h3>LinkButton Example</h3>

      <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
           Text="Click Me" 
           Font-Names="Verdana" 
           Font-Size="14pt" 
           OnClick="LinkButton_Click" 
           runat="server"/>

      <br />

      <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" />

   </form>

</body>
</html>
```

In your specific case, add a [`ContentPlaceHolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.contentplaceholder.aspx) in your master page:

```
<asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
```

In the page where you want the links to appear you add a [`Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.content.aspx) control like so:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

Then `foreach` link you want, do this:

```
foreach (mammifere l in mamlist)
{
    LinkButton linkButton = new LinkButton();

    linkButton.Text = l.Nom;

    linkButton.OnClick= "LinkButton_Click";

    linkButton.ID = l.Nom;     

    Content1.Controls.Add(linkButton);
}
```

Comment: for some reasons, I don't have access to the contentplaceholder

Comment: See my edit... It's been a long time since I worked with ASP.NET WebForms... :)